# How do I call another class from the same trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger on custom object called ShippingAddress. In this trigger it is calling a class called ShippingAddressTriggerHandler. I want to call another class (StagingShippingTriggerHandler) from the same trigger.Below is my trigger code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
trigger ShippingAddress on Shipping_Address__c (after delete, 
                             after insert,  
                             after undelete, 
                             after update, 
                             before delete, 
                             before insert, 
                             before update ) {
    try  
    {
        ITriggerHandler handler = new SingleTriggerHandler (
                                        new ShippingAddressTriggerHandler(),
                                        Trigger.isExecuting,
                                        Trigger.isInsert, 
                                        Trigger.isUpdate, 
                                        Trigger.isDelete, 
                                        Trigger.isBefore, 
                                        Trigger.isAfter, 
                                        Trigger.isUndelete, 
                                        Trigger.new, 
                                        Trigger.newMap, 
                                        Trigger.old, 
                                        Trigger.oldMap, 
                                        Trigger.size );
        handler.process(); 
    }
    catch (AbstractTriggerHandler.InvalidTriggerInvocationException itie)
    {
        SystemExceptionLogger.insertSystemExceptionLogEntry(
                                        itie, 
                                        'Shipping Address Application - Common Use', 
                                        'Shipping Address Trigger', 
                                        SystemExceptionLogger.EXCEPTION_LEVEL_INFO);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SystemExceptionLogger.insertSystemExceptionLogEntry(
                                        e, 
                                        'Shipping Address Trigger Application - Common Use', 
                                        'Shipping Address Trigger', 
                                        SystemExceptionLogger.EXCEPTION_LEVEL_CRITICAL);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be calling the other class from the `SingleTriggerHandler` or whatever dispatcher you have implemented. Calling it from the trigger defeats the purpose of the framework you appear to have implemented

Comment: The   new ShippingAddressTriggerHandler() from the above trigger is a class is my other class name. Can you tell me why is this trigger code so differnt with try and catch.

Comment: If `ITriggerHandler/SingleTriggerHandler` have been written within your company and are commonly used within your company, you should consult the author or look for similar examples in your code base of situations where more than one handler is to be invoked. A little strange that the exception handling isn't internal to the trigger framework.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Trigger framework implemented. Here the class `ITriggerHandler` is main class to execute all the logic sequentially with managing the context.

Go through this class and find the method which get called on the trigger event you want the class to be called. You should be able to get all Trigger Context variable in that class so, utilize them. The closest match is the `SingleTriggerHandler` where you should write the logic.

DO NOT write in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

First thing its a bad practice to write logic inside trigger.

You can follow pattern like below.

1. Trigger

   ```
    trigger ShippingTrigger on Shipping_Address__c (after insert, after update) {
       if(trigger.isAfter) {
           if(trigger.isInsert) {
               new ShippingTriggerTriggerHandler().onAfterInsert();
           }//if
           if(trigger.isUpdate) {
               new ShippingTriggerTriggerHandler().onAfterUpdate();
           }//if
       }//if
   }//ShippingTrigger
   ```

2.trigger Handler

```
public with sharing class ShippingTriggerHandler {
    //Method to execute on After Insert event
    public void onAfterInsert(){
        new ShippingTriggerService().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
    }

    //Method to execute on After Update event
    public void onAfterUpdate(){
        new ShippingTriggerService().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
    }
}
```

3. Service Class.

   ```
    public with sharing class ShippingTriggerService {
       public void serviceClassMethod(List <Sobject>  sObjectList){

       }
    }
   ```

Thanks,
Nachiket