# How to Put Logic of an Apex Trigger in an Apex Class?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an apex trigger that creates a new `Custom2__c` record whenever a new `Custom1__c` record with a `Type__c` having a value of A is inserted.

This is working already, and I am not encountering errors/problems with it. It's just that I want to know how to convert this apex trigger to an apex class, with all the logic inside the apex class instead of the trigger instead.

```
trigger createCustom2OnCustom1 on Custom1__c (after insert) {

    List<Custom2__c> custom2ToInsert = new List<Custom2__c> 

    for (Custom1__c c1 : Trigger.new) {

        if (c1.Type__c = "A") {  

            Custom2__c c2 = new Custom2__c();  
            c2.Field1__c = c1.Field1__c;   

            custom2ToInsert.add(c2);

        } 

    } 

    if(!custom2ToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert custom2ToInsert;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find that there are many different theories on how to structure this, but at the most basic level, it seems most people use public static methods to achieve their goal.

```
public class createCustom2OnCustom1Helper {
  public static void afterInsert(Custom1__c[] records) {
    Custom2__c[] custom2ToInsert = new Custom2__c[0];
    for(Custom1__c record: records) {
      if(record.Type__c == 'A') {
        custom2ToInsert.add(new Custom2__c(Field1__c=record.Field1__c));
      }
    }
    insert custom2ToInsert;
  }
}
```

Which, unsurprisingly, you'd call using a static function call in your trigger:

```
trigger createCustom2OnCustom1 ON Custom1__c(after insert) {
  createCustom2OnCustom1Helper.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
}
```

Note that this is the most basic type of framework. A more disciplined approach is to implement [Service Layers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer); also, read the related documents list on that page for other common patterns. Finally, consider a search on Google for "Apex Code Trigger Handlers", and you'll find other blogs and documentations on how other people implement trigger handlers.

There are many viable designs, and many of them are not "wrong," but you should really just pick one, try it out for a bit, if you like it, continue using it, and if not, tweak it or find another one. A good framework will let you switch to another framework with minimal hassle, simply because well-designed frameworks favor code re-use.

Comment: I've heard that putting all the logic inside the apex class is considered as best practice. Anyway, I appreciate your suggestion and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow pattern like below.
Which helps to define logic such that if there needs some improvement in future,
you just have to modify the SobjectServiceClass class

1. Trigger

   ```
   trigger SObjectTrigger on Sobject (after insert, after update) {
    if(trigger.isAfter) {
       if(trigger.isInsert) {
           new SobjectTriggerHandler().onAfterInsert();
       }//if
       if(trigger.isUpdate) {
           new SobjectTriggerHandler().onAfterUpdate();
       }//if
    }//if
   }//SObjectTrigger
   ```

2.trigger Handler

```
public with sharing class SobjectTriggerHandler {
  //Method to execute on After Insert event
  public void onAfterInsert(){
    new SobjectServiceClass().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
  }

  //Method to execute on After Update event
  public void onAfterUpdate(){
    new SobjectServiceClass().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
  }
}
```

3. Service Class.

   ```
   public with sharing class SobjectServiceClass {
     public void serviceClassMethod(List <Sobject>  sObjectList){

     }
   }
   ```

Also you can go through following question for more details:
[How do I call another class from the same trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150384/how-do-i-call-another-class-from-the-same-trigger/150847#150847)

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: Unfortunately the creator asked to remove the logic from the triggers. But your solution contains if statements, which are of course logic.