# Trigger lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger leadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {
        if (lead.IsConverted ){
            Lead oldl = Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id);
            if (oldl.IsConverted == false && lead.isConverted == true){
                for(Contact con : [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = :lead.ConvertedContactId]){
                    con.DEPRECATE__Type__c = lead.Status ;
                    contactList.add(con);
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    if(contactList.size()>0)
        update contactList;
}
```

Here how can I retrieve contact in bulkify way: 
for example the `for loop` will be on top like:

```
for(Contact con : [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = :trigger.new.ConvertedContactId])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bulkify and optimize your code in this way.

```
trigger leadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

    for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if (l.IsConverted){
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.Id = l.ConvertedContactId;
            c.DEPRECATE__Type__c = l.Status;
            contactList.add(c);
        } 
    }
    if(contactList.size() > 0){
        update contactList;
    }
}
```

**Points to note:**

1.Have handler class for every trigger. Logic should be in that handler class.

2.Avoid unwanted checks in `if`. You can only convert an unconverted lead. So don't need to check if lead is converted previously.

3.Query all the necessary fields of Contact need to manage.

Comment: Thanks but here above in  con.DEPRECATE__Type__c = lead.Status;  how could i get the lead status

Comment: @user40665 You are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Reshma, this check if(contactList.size() > 0) is not necessary. update statement is smart enough to understand to 'Update' only when the list>0. So, just update contactList should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger leadConvert on Lead (after update) {
List<Contact> contactListToUpdate = new List<Contact>();    
Map<Id,Lead> contactIdLeadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
for(Lead objNewlead:System.Trigger.new) {
    if (objlead.IsConverted == true){
        Lead objOldLeadrecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id);
        if (objOldLeadrecord.IsConverted == false && objNewlead.isConverted == true){               
            contactIdLeadMap.put(objNewlead.ConvertedContactId,objNewlead);
        }
    } 
}

if(setContactId.isEmpty() == false) return;
//Commented this code instead use advance for loop which will help you to 
//retrive records using  querymore
//contactList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactId];    
for(Contact objContact : [SELECT Id,DEPRECATE__Type__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIdLeadMap.KeySet()] ){
    objContact.DEPRECATE__Type__c = contactIdLeadMap.get(objContact.Id).Status ;
    contactListToUpdate.add(objContact);
}


if(contactList.isEmpty() == false)
    try{
        update contactList;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
  }
```

Whenever you want to bulkify your code Collections will always there for rescue, take set of contactIds and use that in your SOQL query,
also please check this question which will also help you to understand how to write trigger pattern [How to Put Logic of an Apex Trigger in an Apex Class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154209/how-to-put-logic-of-an-apex-trigger-in-an-apex-class/154240#154240)

You can follow pattern like below. Which helps to define logic such that if there needs some improvement in future, you just have to modify the SobjectServiceClass class

**Trigger**

```
trigger SObjectTrigger on Sobject (after insert, after update) {
 if(trigger.isAfter) {
    if(trigger.isInsert) {
        new SobjectTriggerHandler().onAfterInsert();
    }//if
    if(trigger.isUpdate) {
        new SobjectTriggerHandler().onAfterUpdate();
    }//if
 }//if
}//SObjectTrigger
```

**2.trigger Handler**

```
public with sharing class SobjectTriggerHandler {
  //Method to execute on After Insert event
  public void onAfterInsert(){
    new SobjectServiceClass().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
  }

  //Method to execute on After Update event
  public void onAfterUpdate(){
    new SobjectServiceClass().serviceClassMethod((List<Sobject>)trigger.new);
  }
}
```

**Service Class.**

```
public with sharing class SobjectServiceClass {
  public void serviceClassMethod(List <Sobject>  sObjectList){

  }
}
```